# How to update a record with a constraint and JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using JPA and I would like to update a record. I know that the `save()` method can update a record, but I have a constraint in my database and when I try to update the information I get the following error:

```java
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "register_code_package_unique_key"
  Detail: Key (register_code, package)=(135, AL1689) already exists.
```

In my entity class those fields are this way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "packages", schema = "main", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"registerCode", "package"})
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class PackageEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "packageId")
    private Integer packageId;

    @Column(name = "registerCode")
    private Integer registerCode;
    
    @Column(name = "package")
    private String package;

    @Column(name = "registerDate")
    private LocalDateTime registerDate;
    
    @Column(name = "lastRegisterDate")
    private LocalDateTime lastRegisterDate;

    @Column(name = "employee")
    private Integer employee;
    
    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Float weight;
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you post your full entity code as the save method will only do an update if the entity argument has a populated @Id field

Comment: That is a database error, and it clearly stats that you are trying to update some unique column with some dup value. It is not related to JPA.

Comment: But JPA doesn't have an update method, the update method is ```save()```. If I have a constraint, how can I update the information?

Comment: As @johnnyutts have mentioned, if there is a value in `@Id` field then `save()` will perform the update operation, otherwise `insert` operation. So it seems like you want to update a record, but you are not setting the `@Id` field, and thus JPA tries to insert that record instead of `update`.